# Add a legend for multiple geom_segments while maintaining a "solid" linetype in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a plot using geom_segment and I'd like to add a legend for the different line colours. The only solution I've found suggests modifying the linetype in aes(), but this only works for one segment - when I add a second label to another geom_segment then the linetype becomes dashed and the legend just changes to the new colour.

Here's the code for the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

rib_x <- seq(1,10,0.5)
rib_ymin <- seq(3,12,0.5)
rib_ymax <- c(3.0,4.4,5.55,6.55,7.28,8.1,8.6,9.1,9.52,9.98,10.3,10.62,10.98,11.2,11.4,11.52,11.7,11.8,12)

ggplot(data.frame())+
  geom_segment(aes(x=1, xend=10, y=12, yend=3),colour="dark red",size=1.5)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=1, y=3,xend=10,yend=12),colour="green",size=1.5)+
  stat_smooth(aes(x=rib_x,y=rib_ymax),se=FALSE,colour="dark green",size=1.5)+
  xlab("Agroecological zone")+
  ylab("Productivity")+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, xend = 0, y=2, yend=12), size=1.5, arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.6,"cm")))+
  theme_bw()+
  annotate("text", label="Arid", x=2, y=1)+
  annotate("text", label="Semi-arid", x=5, y=1)+
  annotate("text", label="Humid", x=8, y=1)+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14),axis.text=element_blank(),legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

I'd like to add a legend for the three line colours, where I can also specify the text used in the legend.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Move the `colour` aesthetics inside `aes()` and name them with the actual strings you want to use to label each color. Then add `scale_colour_manual()` at the end to get the specific colors you want. See the example below.

In the "standard" ggplot2 workflow, you would map some categorical column to `colour` inside `aes()` (e.g., `ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Sepal.Width, colour=Species)) + geom_smooth(se=FALSE, method="lm")`) and then the geoms (e.g., points, lines, smooths, etc.) would appear in a different color for each unique value of the categorical column that was mapped to `colour`. Here, we're not using a data frame, so we create "dummy" mappings to the colour aesthetic. Putting them inside `aes()` causes ggplot to generate the legend.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=1, xend=10, y=12, yend=3, colour="name1"), size=1.5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=1, y=3,xend=10,yend=12, colour="name2"), size=1.5) +
  stat_smooth(aes(x=rib_x,y=rib_ymax, colour="name3"),se=FALSE,size=1.5) +
  labs(x="Agroecological zone", y="Productivity", colour="Type") +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, xend = 0, y=2, yend=12), size=1.5, arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.6,"cm"))) +
  annotate("text", label="Arid", x=2, y=1) +
  annotate("text", label="Semi-arid", x=5, y=1) +
  annotate("text", label="Humid", x=8, y=1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14, margin=margin(b=3)),
        axis.title.y=element_text(angle=90)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("name1"="darkred", "name2"="green", "name3"="darkgreen"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's worked! And thanks for the explanation too, that's really helpful.