# Why a second legend is not being included in my ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The plot below is to create a ggplot in which I show the relationship between two variables according to the raw data (points) and according to two different models (`m1` and `m3`), from which I extract the coefficients and I drow two continuous lines. The grey line is just to show a relationship of 1:1.

[image]

```
line_colors <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(7, "Reds")[c(2,4,6)]
line_colors

Plot_a <- ggplot(Todo.6min, aes(x=VeDBA.V13AP, y=VeDBA.X16, colour=ID)) + 
  geom_point(size=1.5,alpha=0.2) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope=1,intercept=0),linetype="dashed",color="grey52",size=1.5) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(strip.background=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x =element_blank(),
        axis.title.y =element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,size = 15),
        axis.line = element_line(),
        panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.text=element_text(size=18),
        legend.title = element_text(size=19, face = "bold"),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))

Plot_a

Plot_b <- Plot_a +
  geom_abline(aes(linetype = "m1"),slope = fixef(mod2b)[2] , intercept = fixef(mod2b)[1], color = line_colors[1], size=1.5) +
  geom_abline(aes(linetype = "m3"),slope = fixef(mod2d)[2] + fixef(mod2d)[3], intercept = fixef(mod2d)[1], color = line_colors[2], size=1.5) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(m1 = "solid", m3 = "solid"),labels = c(m1 = "m1", m3 = "m3")) +
  labs(color = "ID", linetype = expression(Model)) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = line_colors)))
         
Plot_b
```

My doubt is why I do not get a legend for the continuous lines although I used `scale_linetype_manual` for indicating that I wanted a legend in which appears "m1" and "m3" as `legend.text`.

Does anyone know where is the mistake?

Comment: You get legnds only when you map something, usually a data column, but sometimes a ["dummy" value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55404561/496488)), to an aesthetic like `colour` or `linetype` inside the `aes()` function. `scale_linetype_manual` (and other `scale_***` functions) have nothing to do with *generating* a legend; they merely set the specific linetypes, colors, etc. that are used in the plot and the legend.

Comment: Based on a quick look through your code, it looks like you'll need to create a linetype mapping in `aes()` within each `geom_abline` call.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10. I tried adding the code `linetype="whatever"` withing `aes()` in the first `geom_line` but it didn't work. Now I realize about a warning message that I did not share with you. When I run `Plot_b` I get next: `Warning messages:1: geom_abline(): Ignoring `mapping` because `slope` and/or `intercept` were provided.`. So I guess that the problem is related with the fact of using `slope` and `formula`? Or should I include them within `aes()`? Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to manually populate the mapping of `geom_abline()`, and then cut the data so that it matches the number of lines you're drawing. Illustrated below with an inbuilt dataset.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_abline(aes(linetype = c("m1", "m3"),
                  slope = c(0.5, 0.75),
                  intercept = c(0, 0.5)),
              data = iris[1:2,])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For your use case you'd have to substute `slope = c(0.5, 0.75)` by `slope = c(fixef(mod2b)[2], fixef(mod2d)[2])`, etc.